# Elementary OS booting on secure mode only PLEASE HELP

Tags: boot

After a few days without using my laptop and leaving it unpluged/uncharged, when I turned it on today it showed the BIOS screen and date/time was wrong. So I corrected the date/time saved and boot. Now it only boots straight in secure mode, cant connect to wifi, therefore cant update, screen resolution is wrong (thats how I know its secure mode).

Please help! Was working fine last time I used (4 days ago).

Answer (score 2):

my guess is, if your BIOS date/time have suddenly become shifted by themselves, this might be due to the potential CMOS reset. If CMOS has been reset, this means that all your BIOS settings have been reset, including one that's usually called 'Secure Boot'. If that's the case, reboot your laptop, enter BIOS settings, find 'Secure Boot' setting, change it to Disabled, save and reboot.